# Post to Facebook user wall using Facebook.dll in WP7

Tags: c#, facebook, post, windows-phone-7

How to post to user wall in facebook using Facebook.dll in WP7. 
I found one method named PostAsync() but am not able to understand the parameters.
Any help will be thankfull.
Thanks

Comment: Which Facebook.dll are you using? There are a number of libraries available for implementing Facebook applications and the answer to your question will depend on which one you are using.

Comment: I have an error: "The user hasn't authorized the application to perform this action"

Comment: @smalltalk1960s

This is because the user needs to allow your application to publish to their wall. 

To allow posting to the wall within session (so whilst the user is interacting with the application) you'll just need to request the "publish_stream" permission from facebook. 

If you need to publish to their wall offline, you'll need to request "publish_stream" and "offline_access". More details can be found: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions

Check the documentation for the API your using to determine how to prompt the user to allow specific permissions

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Finally succeded in Posting using the follwing code:-

```
var args = new Dictionary<string, object>();
 args["name"] = "Check this out";
 args["link"] = "www.xyz.com";
 args["caption"] = "";
 args["description"] = "description";
 args["picture"] = "";
 args["message"] = "Check this out";
 args["actions"] = "";

FacebookAsyncCallback callBack = new FacebookAsyncCallback(this.postResult);
 fbApp.PostAsync("me/feed", args, callBack);  

    private void postResult(FacebookAsyncResult asyncResult)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(asyncResult);
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

If you're using the Facebook C# SDK you can find their docs here: http://csharpsdk.org/docs/