# WP7 application how to post a local picture with facebook C# SDK?

Tags: windows-phone-7, facebook-c#-sdk

I am developing a WP7 application and want to post a picture to the wall. I find that it need a URI for the picture but if I want to post a local picture from the mobile, what I should specify here or how can i get the uri for the local picture? Thanks a lot!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Post to Facebook user wall using Facebook.dll in WP7](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4757924/post-to-facebook-user-wall-using-facebook-dll-in-wp7)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The last time I looked at working with the Facebook SDK it wasn't possible to post a local photo to the user's wall; you had to have the photo hosted online somewhere already. However you can post to the user's photos section.

There is a [forum post on the App Hub](http://forums.create.msdn.com/forums/p/63646/390044.aspx) that gives the code for doing this. I *think* the [Facebook C# SDK](https://github.com/facebook/csharp-sdk) supports WP7, but I'm not sure if it will simplify this process any further.