# Uploading a photo to facebook in Windows phone 7

Tags: facebook, silverlight-4.0, windows-phone-7

I am not finding any concrete api or reference about uploading a photo to facebook in windows phone 7.I have tried with the latest c# sdk from http://facebooksdk.codeplex.com.
But no luck.Appreciate if you could help me..

Comment: possible duplicate of [Post to Facebook user wall using Facebook.dll in WP7](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4757924/post-to-facebook-user-wall-using-facebook-dll-in-wp7)

Answer (score 2):

This question seems to come up time and time again. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5090865/wp7-application-how-to-post-a-local-picture-with-facebook-c-sdk) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4757924/post-to-facebook-user-wall-using-facebook-dll-in-wp7). I wish Facebook would make it easier :)

The last time I looked at working with the Facebook SDK it wasn't possible to post a local photo to the user's wall; you had to have the photo hosted online somewhere already. However you can post to the user's photos section.

There is a [forum post on the App Hub](http://forums.create.msdn.com/forums/p/63646/390044.aspx) that gives the code for doing this. I *think* the [Facebook C# SDK](https://github.com/facebook/csharp-sdk) supports WP7, but I'm not sure if it will simplify this process any further.

Comment: Thanks.app hub post from bob really works.It is more complicated than i thought