# Post On Facebook Wall From Windows Phone

Tags: facebook, windows-phone-7, share

I want my application to post something on Facebook wall. My application is supposed to run on WP7.

Is there any way of opening a web browser with a default Facebook (hosted on Facebook server) publishing form? I see different websites opening a new window with that form when Share button is clicked and then you click Publish and here you go - the post is on the wall :)

WebBrowserTask is pretty limited and seems to be able to send only GET data but even then... I don't know what kind of data and how named it should be sent. Anyone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not use the [Facebook Developer's Toolkit](http://facebooksdk.codeplex.com/documentation) to post via API instead of trying to use a browser?

Comment: Because when I added reference to Facebook.dll and tried using it in the code, the constructor throws and exception saying that some Microsoft.Conctracts method is missing.

Comment: Have you tried the `CSWinPhone7SimpleApp` sample to see if you have more luck with it?  To save you time and headache, I think it would make more sense to figure out what you need to do to use the existing SDK rather than figuring out how to write your own SDK (unless you want to create an SDK, say as a learning exercise, of course)

Comment: Damn... Downloaded the samples, compiled it and notice that they have Microsoft.Contracts.dll with them. Just used it in my program and at least it passes the current exception point. Thank You!

Answer (score 1):

You can try [Post to Facebook user wall using Facebook.dll in WP7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4757924/post-to-facebook-user-wall-using-facebook-dll-in-wp7/4758572#4758572).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to post on someone other than the user's wall, then the Facebook SDK is required. But if you just want to quickly add the option to share something to Facebook, you could just open a new WebBrowserTask and have it go to http://www.facebook.com/share.php, and just add u and t to the URL. u being the URL to share, and t being the Title.

But from what's been said it seems the SDK is what your going to want.